# Can you partition a U-Boot FIT Image back into its components?

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I recently [found out](https://github.com/siemens/u-boot/tree/master/doc/uImage.FIT) how to create an FIT Image for U-Boot.

According to the `*.its` file, which is needed for creation, the image can contain Kernel, Root File System and Device Tree Blobs.

My question is if there is way to separate a prebuilt FIT Image back into its components (maybe even get a `*its` file back).

Answer (score 2):

Install device-tree-compiler(apt-get install) and download a script split_bootimg.pl(github). Run the script to extract kernel image, ramdisk and the dtb file. Then you got every components. And you can use the device-tree-compiler to extract the device tree file from the dtb.

If you have the "Android Magic not found in image. Giving up." problem, then:

From the split_bootimg.pl, the format of a FIT image should be:

=format (from bootimg.h)

** +-----------------+

** | boot header     | 1 page

** +-----------------+

** | kernel          | n pages

** +-----------------+

** | ramdisk         | m pages

** +-----------------+

** | second stage    | o pages

** +-----------------+

boot-header contains a magic-number field, the script will check the field to verify whether the image is android or not. Below code check the magic number:

```
# Read the Magic
read(INF, $buf, BOOT_MAGIC_SIZE);
unless ($buf eq BOOT_MAGIC) {
die "Android Magic not found in $fn. Giving up.\n";
}
```

So maybe you can comment out the code, or check what the magic number is in your image and modify the script.

Comment: I found this perl script: https://gist.github.com/jberkel/1087743 and used it like this: `split_bootimg.pl image`. This output was produced: `Android Magic not found in image. Giving up.` Can you help me further maybe? My Platform isn't Android btw. I am on bare Linux.

Comment: From the split_bootimg.pl, the format of a FIT image should be:

Comment: ** +-----------------+
** | boot header     | 1 page
** +-----------------+
** | kernel          | n pages
** +-----------------+
** | ramdisk         | m pages
** +-----------------+
** | second stage    | o pages
** +-----------------+

Comment: This seems to work only for a given image structure. But according to the above link there are any configurations possible. I didn't get it to work with my Image.